# Getting error while building Bitcoind on m1 MAC OS

Tags: macos, boost, bitcoin, apple-m1, bitcoind

So I'm trying to build bitcoind on big sur in my m1 mac through following the documentation for building bitcoind for OS X: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-osx.md and I've had the same error every time I try and build. Here are the steps I take:

> brew install autoconf automake berkeley-db4 libtool boost miniupnpc openssl pkg-config protobuf qt5

> git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git

> cd bitcoin

> ./autogen.sh

> ./configure --with-gui=no

After the configuration I get the following message:

> checking for boostlib >= 1.58.0 (105800)... configure: We could not detect the boost libraries (version 1.58.0 or higher). If you have a staged boost library (still not installed) please specify $BOOST_ROOT in your environment and do not give a PATH to --with-boost option.  If you are sure you have boost installed, then check your version number looking in <boost/version.hpp>. See http://randspringer.de/boost for more documentation.

I don't get why it's not detecting the library...

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it this way:

```
cd depends/
make
# After completing this step, you will see one new folder (arm-apple-darwin20.4.0) in /bitcoin/depends. The version number may change

# Go back to bitcoin folder
cd ..

# Set up the compilation tool
./configure --with-gui=no --prefix=$PWD/depends/arm-apple-darwin20.4.0
# change the version ...darwin20.x.x with what you have in depends directory

# Start to compile bitcoin
make HOST=arm-apple-darwin20

make check
```

You can see the bitcoind binary in the src directory. Enjoy :)

> source:
> https://gist.github.com/awesome-doge/9bfbd1d3fd9b725c4df224433fa3596e